# $f\colon B(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ continuous and $\int f\,dz=0$ for every circle $|z|=r$ implies $f$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following statement true?

---

*Statement :* Let $f\colon B(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous mapping such that for every $r\in(0,1)$ 
$$
  \int_{|z|=r} f(z)\,dz=0
  ,
$$
then $f$ is analytic on $B(0,1)$.

---

Here $B(0,1)$ denotes the unit ball $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon\ |z|<1\}$.

I tried using an analogue of Morera's Theorem (*) proof in the following way:
Let $z\in B(0,1)$ and define the curve $\gamma_z$ as

[image]

if $\mathrm{Re}(z)>0$ or $\mathrm{Re}(z)<0$ ($w$ on image above). Note that if $z=iy$ with $y<0$, then we have two different curves approaching $z$.

Consider $F\colon B(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by
$$
  \int_{\gamma_z} f(\zeta)\,d\zeta
  .
$$
Even when $z=iy$ with $y<0$, $F$ is well defined since the integral of $f$ over such circle is zero. I want to prove that $F'=f$ but I don't even know if that's possible... Is the statement above even true?

---

(*) Morera's Theorem states that if $f$ is a continuous function which satisfies $\int_{\partial\triangle}f=0$ for every triangle contained in $f$'s domain, then $f$ is analytic. To prove it one construct's a function $F$ such that $F'=f$...

---

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @Conrad can you elaborate on the sufficiency of this condition?

Comment: @Conrad Sufficiency fails: Let $f(z) = |z|.$

Comment: yes I realized this so I will delete the comment - the problem is that the function is only "analytic" in $\theta$ on each circle (the Fourier expansion has no negative powers) but not in $z$

Answer (score 1):

Your condition holds for every $f(z)$ satisfying $f(-z) = f(z)$, so it's not hard to find counterexamples that aren't analytic, such as $f(z) = |z|$.